# SSL certificate not accepted by Firefox

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

For some reason, Firefox today started issuing warnings about the SSL certificates on our web applications, but supplies very little information. Everything works fine in IE/Edge and Chrome. The application is at https://ps.ecco.com

How can I find out more about what's going wrong with the certificates and how do I solve the issue?

Comment: What does the warning say?

Comment: Connection closed by server. But have a look at what https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ tells, there are a couple of oddities in the server setup, and their simulated handshake for a number of Firefox browsers also fails.